# How do I lock my AMD overscan to 0% with HDMI?

Tags: ati, hdmi, proprietary

I use an external monitor with my laptop, connected over HDMI. Every time I boot, the viewable area in the monitor is always reduced.

Running the AMD Catalyst Control Centre and setting my display to 0% overscan resolves the issue, but I have to do this every time I boot the computer. I always ensure my HDMI cable is connected before I start my laptop.

I have an AMD Radeon HD 7700M Series, using AMD proprietary drivers.